# Is there a way to measure the information content (or difference) in two matrices?

Tags: inference, information-theory, mutual-information

**Prologue**

I have a matrix $N$ with dimensions $I\times J$, $I >> J$, and $n_{ij}$ is assumed to follow a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda_{ij}$. Using a method (say *NtoM*), I reduce $N$ to a matrix $M$ with dimensions $I \times K$ (rows correspond to that of $N$, however columns are not representing the same quantities as in $N$), $I >> K$, and the entries of $M$ are positive real numbers.

*Edit* (thanks to @whuber's comment)

This is the relation between $N$ and $M$:

For any $i \in \{1,\ldots, I\}$ and a particular $j$, $\lambda_{ij}$ will be on of the $m_{ik}$, $k \in \{1,\ldots, K\}$. However, the key is that for a particular $i$, $\lambda_{ij_1}$ and $\lambda_{ij_2}$ need not be the same if $j_1\neq j_2$. $K$ can be assumed to be less than $J$.

**Question**

Is there a way to measure the difference of information content (gain or loss) in reducing matrix $N$ to $M$ using the method *NtoM*?

Comment: I don't know if I am being coherent here. Please let me know if I need to elaborate (Sorry!).

Comment: Yep, more detail is needed.  Are you sure that the Poisson parameter can be different in *every* cell?  If so, there doesn't seem to be much to go on, because that seems to mean you have $I J$ separate estimation problems.  The matrix structure doesn't play any apparent role in what you've described.

Comment: add up the [differential entropies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) of the individual matrix elements (assuming the $n_{ij}$ are independent of each other) and compare the entropy sum of $N$ to the entropy sum of $M$ ?

Comment: @whuber do my edits make the question answerable?